# Inputting the correct condition for a for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to write a small program dealing the earthquakes and magnitudes.

When the program is run, it asks the user to input a number for how many earthquakes the user wants to submit magnitudes for.  Depending on the response, the program then prompts the user to enter a magnitude for each earthquake.  I have written the following code below but am having trouble with the `for loop`.

Obviously in the for loop, putting `i <= numberOfEarthquakes` disallows the program from compiling correctly.  What is a simple way to give `i` a condition that correlates to the inputted number from the user.  Much thanks.

(this is a smaller part of a larger program that I am hoping to write)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Earthquakes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many magnitudes will you enter? ");
        String numberOfEarthquakes = console.next();

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfEarthquakes; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter magnitude for earthquake " + i);
            String magnitudeOfEarthquake = console.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the compiler error.  You need to parse the string into a number.

Comment: parse console.next() like this Integer.parseInt(numberOfEarthquakes);

Comment: @Zeus Don't do that. That is just reinventing the wheel and confusing people. Instead, do `console.nextInt();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make this `String numberOfEarthquakes = console.next();` to `int numberOfEarthquakes = console.nextInt();`

You can not compare `String` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `numberOfEarthquakes`  from String to Integer. Use `Integer.parseInt(numberOfEarthquakes)` to convert String to Intger.